# What do these parentheses mean when calling an object?

Tags: java, syntax, parentheses, function-call

Just came across this statement and was wondering why this function call had what at first looked like a cast?

```
SomeClass bo = new SomeClass(); // blabla something like that to initialize the object variable
(bo).setValue(bo.getValue().negate());
```

As I have not yet seen this syntax - what does it do compared to a simple

```
bo.setValue(bo.getValue().negate());
```

?

Comment: This looks like an anonymous class. But I fail to see the point in an anonymous subclass of `Object` .

Comment: the braces only enforce precedence of an expression over another operator with usually higher precedence, eg. `(1 + 2) * 3`. Here they do not change the meaning since there is no operator in the expression inside it*

Comment: @Arnaud I think the issue is on the second line... The first is just an example of initialization--misleading though.

Comment: There is no difference between `(bo).setValue(...)` and `bo.setValue(...)`. The parenthesis around `bo` are superfluous.

Comment: Question title is misleading. Your question is about the `()` around `bo`. `()` are called "parentheses" (or "round brackets"), while `{}` are called "braces" (or "curly brackets"). See [Bracket vs brace](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/bracket-vs-brace).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(bo).setValue(bo.getValue().negate())` and `bo.setValue(bo.getValue().negate())` are identical statements and the parentheses are reduntant here.

They are needed though when we write expressions like

```
Object o;
(o = new Object()).toString();  // class java.lang.Object
```

If we had omitted them,

```
Object o;
o = new Object().toString();  // class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Which we should not do at all, even if we can.

Comment: @lu.koerfer the example I provided isn't practical at all, but sometimes this style `(o = new Object())` is very helpful (let me find good cases)

Comment: @lu.koerfer here is a more reasonable usage (from `java.io.ObjectStreamClass`) https://pastebin.com/sLsRwc86